# Adding table cells with UIPicker values selected

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I am struggling to think about the logic by how i can achieve this. Here's my question :

I am trying to add a picker view (plist) with 3 columns. wherein the second column is dependent on the first one and the third column independent.
say for example :
 1st column: Country Name,
 2nd column : State and
third with yes,no or both options.
Then click add button to save and display these selected values(of picker view).
I want to keep an add another button so that user can select another option from the picker view and display the selection again.

I wanted to know if later on the user wants to edit the selection made earlier than is it possible to auto-populate the options in the picker view for each of them, if selected, like, if i select first added value, then it will populate it in picker view, popping out from bottom and make changes and save it again.For e.g., If the user wants to change the value in third field later.

Sorry, but i am not getting, like is this possible or there is another way to do the same.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you display the picker, you need to include code something like this:

```
// The first row in the first column should be selected
[myPicker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:NO];

// Pick the second row in the second column:
[myPicker selectRow:1 inComponent:1 animated:NO];

// Pick the first row in the third column:
[myPicker selectRow:0 in
```

Comment: thanks man, but i want to show the image regarding the question but i don't have much reputation points. I can select the values, but how to retrieve those values again after killing the app and edit them.

Comment: If you can post the picture somewhere else, you can post a **link** to your picture.

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/67684147/Screen%20Shot%202012-03-17%20at%207.23.57%20PM.png
Please take a look at the above link. When we click edit button, then picker will only pop out with the values selected as in that table cell so that we can edit any of the fields.